# Iterate over unique list created from string split

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a list of domains:

```
---
domains:
 - foo.bar
 - baz.bar
```

I have tasks, where I need to iterate over these domains, extract domain tail, make an unique list of these tails and then create directories named by these tails.

Something like this but AFAIK jinja2 doesn't support list comprehension:

```
---
- name: Ensure all directories exist
  file:
    path: "/tmp/sandbox/{{ item }}"
    state: directory
  with_items: "[domain.split('.')[-1] for domain in domains] | unique"
```

Is it possible or do I need to create a custom jinja2 filter? Will this work?

```
---
- name: Ensure all directories exist
  file:
    path: "/tmp/sandbox/{{ item }}"
    state: directory
  with_items: "{{ domain_tails | my_custom_filter }}"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with `map` and `regex_search`:

```
- debug: msg="Ensure dir for {{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ domains | map('regex_search','\\w+$') | list | unique }}"
```

`\w+$` match the last word (i.e. domain tail after dot).
Note that the slash is escaped, because it is inside double quotes.